# Google Maps sdk with voice navigation direction in IOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I´ve been reading the documentation of the Google Maps SDK for iOS and I didn't see anything about voice navigation direction and route on the map.

Do anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

I correct my previous answer this is possible. You use the google directions API as outlined in this link:

You send your direction request and it returns the directions either as json or xml as per your preference. Gives you coordinates of each point on the route.

You send a request to `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputformat?parameters`

So if you want to return the directions as json the request would be:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ORIGIN_LOCATION&destination=DESTINATION_LOCATION&sensor=FALSE`

the `ORIGIN_LOCATION` and `DESTINATION_LOCATION` can either be a latitude and longitude seperated by a comma e.g. `latitude,longitude` or a location search string e.g `Eiffel+Tower+,+Paris+France` (The search string has to be url encoded).

The sensor parameter is another compulsory parameter and asks whether the device sending the request can detect its own location.

For example for the directions from the eiffel tower to the louvre museum are given on the following link as json:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Louver+museum+Paris&destination=Eiffel+Tower+Paris+France&sensor=false

And to return it as XML:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Louver+museum+Paris&destination=Eiffel+Tower+Paris+France&sensor=false

Comment: Google Maps for iOS is unlimited queries.  What domain does the API request for directions fall under?

Comment: I edited my answer with more details,more information can be found here in the google documentation:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests